# In Crystal how do I convert miliseconds since 01/01/2012 to a date?

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

In Crystal Reports 2008, how do I convert miliseconds since 01/01/2012 to a date variable?

Thank you for any help,
Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 86400000 ms in a day. So,

```
local numbervar days := ceiling({table.ms} / 86400000);
dateadd("d",days,#01/01/2012#);
```